# react-router gives warning and then doesn't work

Tags: react-router

For some reason I get a complaint in chrome from

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, DefaultRoute} from 'react-router';
import App from "components/app"
import FindView from "components/find";
import RememberView from "components/remember";
import MetaView from "components/meta";
import ExploreView from "components/explore";

export default (
  <Route name='pkm' path='/' handler={App}>
   <DefaultRoute handler={RememberView} />
   <Route name="remember" handler={RememberView} />
   <Route name="find" handler={FindView} />
   <Route name="meta" handler={MetaView} />
   <Route name="explore" handler={ExploreView} />
 </Route>
);
```

at the DefaultRoute line that looks like 
React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components.

I don't see why this is.  All the router examples I have seen for ES6 usage look similar to this.  What am I missing?

And when I attempt to run it I get that it doesn't know what Router is?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Router from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import App from 'components/app'

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, (App, state) => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App {...state}/>,      document.getElementById('content'));
});
```

module.js:8Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of undefined.

So I am obviously not getting something.

Comment: The first part is because DefaultRoute is not IndexRoute.  I am still stuck on the second.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of react-router are you using? In the latest version, Router module does not have a run function defined.

In the latest version, the configuration is as follows

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router routes={routes} />
, document. getElementById('content'))
```

For more details refer the [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  I was on a more recent version.  I reworked the code in line with the github for react-router documentation and resolved the problem.